# Add CSS from a .css file to a material component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to material UI. here, I  have a css file which has following ,

```
.bgItem {
 font-size: 14px;
}
```

And my component is like ,

```
 <MenuItem key={status.Id} value={status.Value} classes={css.bgItem}>
       {status.Description}
 </MenuItem>
```

I tried using this way `classes={css.bgItem}`. I actually dont want to use the inline styles ,like creating a object of styles in the component itself. So, I have different css file for this.

Can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `className` prop in this case:

```
<MenuItem key={status.Id} value={status.Value} className="bgItem">
```

the above one is a static one. If you want it dynamic then you can use:

```
<MenuItem key={status.Id} value={status.Value} classes={bgItem}>
```

Here `{bgItem}` is a variable and it may contain some dynamic value.

Comment: No here, The thing is that we need to override because by default the styles of the MenuItem class gets applied not the one which I applied

Comment: See, if your css file is included in the component then you can override it as it will be the updated one or you might take a look into `!important;` css property. `.bgItem {
 font-size: 14px !important;
}`

Comment: Yes I actually have this solution using !important. But sorry I really dont think we should use this

Comment: Look @ganeshk there are multiple ways like you know that id selector has the highest preference in the dom. You can assign one and use that like: `#bgItemId.bgItem { font-size: 14px; }`

Comment: Yeah one is also there. Can you help me with one. if I have a tabindex = 0 to one of the li element then how do I select that element. like using 
li > tabindex  kind of thing